# Как вывести на экран сообщение "Число меньше нуля"?

Tags: c#

Не могу понять что написать в блоке else в случае если число окажется меньше нуля, чтобы выводило на экран "Число меньше нуля" [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А теперь встаньте на наше место и подумайте, мы знаем какой у вас там проект? Консоль? Веб? Полноценный UI? Может мобилка? Везде ведь по-разному вывод делается, а вы нам тупо дали скрин и спрашиваете "Как?"... Ну ок, для консоли `Console.WriteLine("текст");`, тычем пальцем в небо.

Comment: Да, мой косяк что не уточнил, обычное консольное приложение. Если написать Console.WriteLine("..."); то выдаёт ошибку: не все пути к коду возвращают значение

Comment: @Valerons Не все пути возвращают значение, потому что Ваш метод должен всегда возвращать `double`. Если в блоке `else` Вы пишете `Console.WriteLine("Text")`, то кроме этого нужно еще и вернуть что-нибудь типа `double`

Comment: Кажется, что a<0 в данном случае является поводом выбросить исключение и обработать его в вызывающем методе. Т.е. в else напишем `throw new Exception("Число меньше нуля"), а в вызывающем коде (main?) обработаем исключение и выведем его текст

Answer (score 0):

Код

```
static double TestMethod(double a)
{
  if(a < 0) throw new Exception("Число меньше нуля");
  return Math.Pow(a,2);
}
```

Comment: Можно однострочником: `static double TestMethod(double a) => a > 0 ? Math.Pow(a, 2) : throw new ArgumentException("Число меньше нуля");`

Comment: Я в стиле вопроса реализовал